# Pandas: Select rows and add on the right as multiple sets of columns (reshape?)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'pid': [10,20,10,30], 
    'sid': [1,1,2,3],
    'data1': ['a','b','a','c'],
    'data2': ['q','w','e','e'],
})

   pid  sid data1 data2
0   10    1     a     q
1   20    1     b     w
2   10    2     a     e
3   30    3     c     e
```

Can be many rows `data`. Perhaps, can use `index = ['pid', 'sid']`.

How I can transform it to Excel in the following format?

That is, index by `pid`, select row blocks by the  'sid', with iteration by incrementation of it. Then add these as blocks of columns to the right.

```py
sid   1             2              3
pid   data1  data2  data1  data2   data1  data2
 10   a      q      a      e       None   None
 20   b      w      None   None    None   None
 30   None   None   None   None    c      e
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks you for the common help link. But unfortunately, it's no solution there. Testing all the options will take a week, and I doubt that I will find a solution. In this case, there may be a mass of columns like `dataN`, and a mass of `pid` and `sid`. While, `pivot()` requires a specific one column with new columns lists, and doesn't control subdivides by multiple columns.

Comment: as you can see from the answer of @r.ook, doing a pivot `df.pivot(index='pid',columns='sid')` and even not specifying the values will work with any number of column data really. the two other steps are mostly "cosmetic" while necessary I understand that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very good link in the comment. However to answer your specific question, here's a way to achieve it:

```
>>> df = df.pivot(index='pid',columns='sid',values=['data1','data2'])
>>> df
    data1           data2          
sid     1    2    3     1    2    3
pid                                
10      a    a  NaN     q    e  NaN
20      b  NaN  NaN     w  NaN  NaN
30    NaN  NaN    c   NaN  NaN    e
```

This gives you the proper pivot, but not necessarily in the order you want it.  So we'll need to swap the level on the columns:

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel()
>>> df
sid     1     2     3     1     2     3
    data1 data1 data1 data2 data2 data2
pid                                    
10      a     a   NaN     q     e   NaN
20      b   NaN   NaN     w   NaN   NaN
30    NaN   NaN     c   NaN   NaN     e
```

And then sort it:

```
>>> df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
>>> df
sid     1           2           3      
    data1 data2 data1 data2 data1 data2
pid                                    
10      a     q     a     e   NaN   NaN
20      b     w   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
30    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     c     e
```

---

Or you could just chain the methods together:

```
>>> df = df.pivot(index='pid',columns='sid',values=['data1','data2']).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
>>> df 
sid     1           2           3      
    data1 data2 data1 data2 data1 data2
pid                                    
10      a     q     a     e   NaN   NaN
20      b     w   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
30    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     c     e
```

Comment: you could chain everything because `swaplevel` can be applied to a dataframe directly and take axis=1 as argument but it would not make fewer steps ^^

Comment: Thanks @Ben.T, I was *just* updating my answer lol.  These types of shortcuts are not always immediate obvious to me, so appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!